# Using logical comparison together with groupby in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
{'item': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'B',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'C',
  14: 'C',
  15: 'C',
  16: 'C',
  17: 'D',
  18: 'D'},
 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-05-02 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-05-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-05-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-06-13 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-05-04 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-05-05 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-05-06 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-05-07 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-05-08 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-05-09 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-05-10 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-06-14 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-06-15 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2021-06-16 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2021-07-23 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2021-07-08 00:00:00')},
 'price': {0: 249,
  1: 249,
  2: 253,
  3: 260,
  4: 260,
  5: 13,
  6: 13,
  7: 13,
  8: 13,
  9: 17,
  10: 17,
  11: 17,
  12: 17,
  13: 123,
  14: 123,
  15: 123,
  16: 123,
  17: 12,
  18: 12}}
```

which looks like this:

```
  item       Date  price
0     A 2021-05-02    249
1     A 2021-05-02    249
2     A 2021-05-02    253
3     A 2021-05-03    260
4     A 2021-06-13    260
5     B 2021-05-03     13
6     B 2021-05-04     13
7     B 2021-05-05     13
8     B 2021-05-06     13
9     B 2021-05-07     17
10    B 2021-05-08     17
11    B 2021-05-09     17
12    B 2021-05-10     17
13    C 2021-06-14    123
14    C 2021-06-15    123
15    C 2021-06-16    123
16    C 2021-07-23    123
17    D 2021-07-07     12
18    D 2021-07-08     12
```

As you might see, the `price` of an `item` changes over time. What I want to do is to have a column that indicates when a price changes for each item. Now, My first idea was that I could check if the price in the previous row is the same as in the current row (within) a group.

Now, I was convinced that I could do something like this:

```
df_changes['changed'] =  df_changes.groupby(['item'])['price'].eq(df_changes['price'])
```

to compare row values within a group (returning a boolean) and then translating this to integers to get:

```
change_item_num  diffsum  Step  
0                 0        0     0  
1                 1        0     0  
2                 1        1     1  
3                 1        1     2  
4                 1        0     2  
5                 0        0     0  
6                 1        0     0  
7                 1        0     0  
8                 1        0     0  
9                 1        1     1  
10                1        0     1  
11                1        0     1  
12                1        0     1  
13                0        0     0  
14                1        0     0  
15                1        0     0  
16                1        0     0  
17                0        0     0  
18                1        0     0
```

where the `step` column marks changes.

But I was wrong. Whatever I do, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'eq'
```

Instead, I found a workaround that I am very unhappy about:

```
j = df_changes.price 
k = df_changes.item_num

df_changes['change_price'] = j.eq(j.shift()).astype(int)
df_changes['change_item_num'] = k.eq(k.shift()).astype(int)

df_changes['diffsum'] = abs(df_changes['change_price']-df_changes['change_item_num'])
df_changes['Step'] = df_changes.groupby('item')['diffsum'].cumsum()+1
```

which returns:

```
item       Date  price  item_num  change_price  change_item_num  diffsum  \
0     A 2021-05-02    249         1             0                0        0   
1     A 2021-05-02    249         1             1                1        0   
2     A 2021-05-02    253         1             0                1        1   
3     A 2021-05-03    260         1             0                1        1   
4     A 2021-06-13    260         1             1                1        0   
5     B 2021-05-03     13         2             0                0        0   
6     B 2021-05-04     13         2             1                1        0   
7     B 2021-05-05     13         2             1                1        0   
8     B 2021-05-06     13         2             1                1        0   
9     B 2021-05-07     17         2             0                1        1   
10    B 2021-05-08     17         2             1                1        0   
11    B 2021-05-09     17         2             1                1        0   
12    B 2021-05-10     17         2             1                1        0   
13    C 2021-06-14    123         3             0                0        0   
14    C 2021-06-15    123         3             1                1        0   
15    C 2021-06-16    123         3             1                1        0   
16    C 2021-07-23    123         3             1                1        0   
17    D 2021-07-07     12         4             0                0        0   
18    D 2021-07-08     12         4             1                1        0   

    Step  
0      1  
1      1  
2      2  
3      3  
4      3  
5      1  
6      1  
7      1  
8      1  
9      2  
10     2  
11     2  
12     2  
13     1  
14     1  
15     1  
16     1  
17     1  
18     1
```

Surely, there must be an easier way. If not, can anyone explain WHY I cannot use `eq` or any other logical comaprison within a groupby?

Thankful for any new knowledge!

Comment: did you think of `transfrom` with callback, using `shift(1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the current row with the previous row in the `price` column to identify the locations where `price` changes, then group the mask by the `item` column and calculate cumulative sum to assign the sequence of numbers to each group identifying the change in price column per `item`

```
m = df['price'] != df['price'].shift()
df['step'] = m.groupby(df['item']).cumsum()
```

---

```
print(df)

   item        Date  price  step
0     A  2021-05-02    249     1
1     A  2021-05-02    249     1
2     A  2021-05-02    253     2
3     A  2021-05-03    260     3
4     A  2021-06-13    260     3
5     B  2021-05-03     13     1
6     B  2021-05-04     13     1
7     B  2021-05-05     13     1
8     B  2021-05-06     13     1
9     B  2021-05-07     17     2
10    B  2021-05-08     17     2
11    B  2021-05-09     17     2
12    B  2021-05-10     17     2
13    C  2021-06-14    123     1
14    C  2021-06-15    123     1
15    C  2021-06-16    123     1
16    C  2021-07-23    123     1
17    D  2021-07-07     12     1
18    D  2021-07-08     12     1
```